# Mitigating 2.4GHz interference from 0-5V analog signaling line

Tags: differential, interference, single-ended

I am chasing my tail on a project and cannot seem to find a way out of the hole.

I have a small 18mm 40kHz piezo transducer running through a powered precision rectifier+preamp circuit. This tiny powered sensor package is placed at a target location picking up vibrations and turning them into a positive waveform. The sensor and its piggyback board operate on 5VDC, and transmit the waveform back clamped at 2.5V.

Presently, the cable passes near by a wifi radio antenna that is imparting periodic 3.7V spikes into the  waveform at the receiver end.

I have verified the interference is from that wifi antenna.

Since relocating the cable or wifi antenna is not possible for the client I have been stuck on shielding measures. I am using RS-485 Belden cable with a foil and braid, terminated at ground (single ended) at the receiver. Doing this reduced the magnitude of the interference spikes by about 0.3V but didn't eliminate them.

My only option left I believe is to convince the client to ship the signal back on a differential signal instead of single-ended which is problematic because their existing analog-front-end cannot be modified to support a differential input. Is this my only other real option left, if practical shielding options have been exhausted? How else can I mitigate this interference? Filtering is also questionable because the 40kHz signal is within the realm of this interference, as well.

Shown below is the steady-state circuit (two separate sensor nodes) where the yellow passes nearby the Wifi antenna and the blue is placed far away from the antenna.

[image]

Comment: Where is your ground? It would be useful to provide a diagram of the setup. Pictures are also useful

Comment: Measuring 2.4 GHz interference is tricky, especially with a 50 MHz scope and what looks like an x10 probe. How are you probing? A picture of the measurement setup would help a lot.

Comment: Agree with @user1850479...what the 'scope is seeing isn't GHz, but perhaps a secondary effect related to WIFI transmission. Have you tried ferrite on cables?

Comment: Often a 2.4 GHz interference only becomes a problem if some semiconductor structures in the reciever have a recifying effect. So a low pass L/C filter in MHz range on the receiver side has a chance.